# What is wrong with this simple read syntax?

Tags: python, pandas, import

This is from IBM python for data analyst. I am using Kaggle for python.
Its a simple function which is supposed to import data from the url into python and check if the data has been successfully imported by printing the first 5 rows of the data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data"
df = pd.read_csv(url, header = None)
Print("The First Five Rows Of Data are")
df.head(5)
```

The following error followed after a few different tries. I have no idea where to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1349                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1350                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1351             except OSError as err: # timeout error

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1280         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1281         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1282 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1326             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1327         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1328 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1275             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1276         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1277 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1035         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1036         self.send(msg)
   1037 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in send(self, data)
    975             if self.auto_open:
--> 976                 self.connect()
    977             else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in connect(self)
   1442 
-> 1443             super().connect()
   1444 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in connect(self)
    947         self.sock = self._create_connection(
--> 948             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    949         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    706     err = None
--> 707     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    708         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    751     addrlist = []
--> 752     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    753         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/185401550.py in <module>
      3 
      4 url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data"
----> 5 df = pd.read_csv(url, header = None)
      6 Print("The First Five Rows Of Data are")
      7 df.head(5)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    584     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    585 
--> 586     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    587 
    588 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    480 
    481     # Create the parser.
--> 482     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    483 
    484     if chunksize or iterator:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    809             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    810 
--> 811         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    812 
    813     def close(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1038             )
   1039         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1040         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1041 
   1042     def _failover_to_python(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
     49 
     50         # open handles
---> 51         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
     52         assert self.handles is not None
     53 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/base_parser.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
    227             memory_map=kwds.get("memory_map", False),
    228             storage_options=kwds.get("storage_options", None),
--> 229             errors=kwds.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
    230         )
    231 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    612         compression=compression,
    613         mode=mode,
--> 614         storage_options=storage_options,
    615     )
    616 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in _get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    310         # assuming storage_options is to be interpreted as headers
    311         req_info = urllib.request.Request(filepath_or_buffer, headers=storage_options)
--> 312         with urlopen(req_info) as req:
    313             content_encoding = req.headers.get("Content-Encoding", None)
    314             if content_encoding == "gzip":

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
    210     import urllib.request
    211 
--> 212     return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
    213 
    214 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    523             req = meth(req)
    524 
--> 525         response = self._open(req, data)
    526 
    527         # post-process response

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    541         protocol = req.type
    542         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 543                                   '_open', req)
    544         if result:
    545             return result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in https_open(self, req)
   1391         def https_open(self, req):
   1392             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
-> 1393                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
   1394 
   1395         https_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1350                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1351             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1352                 raise URLError(err)
   1353             r = h.getresponse()
   1354         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

Comment: I think the error is quite explicit "*Temporary failure in name resolution*", your system has a hard time resolving the domain name in your URL. You most likely won't fix it by tweaking your code. Rather try to check if your computer has proper network access.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Network is fine on the device. However processing the code in Kaggle is taking a while (~10-15secs). Maybe its  because of that delay.